# How do I test a GraphQL endpoint inside Api Platform?

Tags: graphql, phpunit, api-platform.com, symfony6

I use GraphQL in my Api Platform application v3.1 (and Symfony 6) and I am trying to test my different queries and mutations but I don't know how to pass a query to the request.

What I have already done:

```
final class Test extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testProfile(): void
    {
        $client = self::createClient();
 
        $fixtures = $this->databaseTool
            ->loadFixtures([
                UserTestFixtures::class
            ])
            ->getReferenceRepository();
        
        $user = $fixtures->getReference('user_operator');

        $token = $this->getToken([
            'username' => $user->getEmail(),
            'password' => 'S3cret'
        ]);
 
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'api/graphql', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization => 'Bearer ' . $token
            ],
            'extra' => [
                'parameters' => [
                    'operations' => '{
                        "query": "query getProfile {
                            profileUser {
                                id
                                firstName
                                lastName
                                email
                            }
                        }"
                    }'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

So my question is: how can I pass a GraphQL query to the request ?

In the example above, I have the following error message: "GraphQL query is not valid".

Thank you

Comment: GraphQL requests are POSTs